# What is the confidence interval for quantile regression? And how to find other than default?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, quantile

There is a way to construct the confidence interval for quantile regression:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- x + 2*rnorm(1000)
rqm1 <- rq(y~x)
summary(rqm1)
```

What is the default? Is it 5%? How to find another one, like 10%?

Comment: This is a good question (I couldn't find the answer in the documentation) but I think it belongs on StackOverflow since it is just about `R`, not about the statistical properties of quantile regression.

Comment: Have you looked at the vignette, http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/rq/vig.pdf? On p.4, it says "The resulting table gives the estimated intercept and slope in the first column and confidence intervals for these parameters in the second and third columns. By default, these confidence intervals are computed by the rank inversion method de- scribed in Koenker (2005), Section 3.4.5."

Comment: I did, but it doesn't say what is the default and how to change it to another one.

Answer (score 3):

The default alpha level for the `summary.qr` method is `.1`, which corresponds to a confidence interval width of `.9`. I puzzled over this for quite some time because it just isn't clearly documented.

The confidence intervals when `se = "rank"` (the default for data with fewer than 1001 rows) are calculated by refitting the model with `rq.fit.br`, which is the underlying mechanism used by `rq`. If you look at the documentation for `rq.fit.br`, you can see there is an `alpha` argument that is set to `.1` by default. If you pass an `alpha` argument to `summary.rq`, it will be passed to `rq.fit.br` and you will get the confidence interval you're looking for.

Same result as `summary(rqm1)`:

`summary(rqm1, alpha = .1)`

95% interval:

`summary(rqm1, alpha = .05)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting conf. interval directly as by default the summary function for rq uses rank method to estimate CIs
So you can use summary.rq function and set se="boot","nid","iid","ker" option to obtain different Standard errors. I have set it to se="boot".It gives you standard errors for your coefficients which you can use in qunatile formula to find CI.

for 90% use

```
qnorm(0.95)
```

for 95% use

```
qnorm(0.975)
```

The complete code

```
library(quantreg)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- x + 2*rnorm(1000)
rqm1 <- rq(y~x)
summary.rq(rqm1, se="boot") -> rqm2
coef=rqm2$coefficients[,1] 
err=rqm2$coefficients[,2]  
ci <- list()
for (i in 1:length(coef)){
ci[[i]] <- coef[i] + c(-1,1)*err[i]*qnorm(0.975)}
```

This returns a confidence intervals for your intercept and all your variables